# How do I stop PIL from swapping height/width when rotating an image 90°?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am using [PIL](https://python-pillow.github.io/) to rotate an image.  This works in general, except when I rotate the image exactly 90° or 270°, in which case the x and y measurements swap.  That is, given this image:

```
>>> img.size
(93, 64)
```

If I rotate it by 89° I get this:

```
>>> img.rotate(89).size
(93, 64)
```

And by 91° I get this:

```
>>> img.rotate(91).size
(93, 64)
```

But if I rotate it by either 90° or 270°, I find the height and width
swapped:

```
>>> img.rotate(90).size
(64, 93)
>>> img.rotate(270).size
(64, 93)
```

What's the correct way to prevent this?

Comment: It looks like 90 and 270 are special cases and do what *most* people expect. You may be out of luck, although you can use the `expand` option to make it consistent.

Comment: I don't think `expand` by itself will work; I'm writing to a fixed-sized screen.  Possibly `expand` and some sort of `crop` operation.

Comment: Update for fellow googlers: Pillow, the excellent PIL fork, fixed this issue in 3.0.0. Rotating 90 or 270 degrees now keeps the same dimension, so you need to set expand=True if you want the dimensions to actually change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm hoping someone comes up with a more graceful solution, but this seems to work for now:

```
img = Image.open('myimage.pbm')

frames = []
for angle in range(0, 365, 5):
    # rotate the image with expand=True, which makes the canvas
    # large enough to contain the entire rotated image.
    x = img.rotate(angle, expand=True)

    # crop the rotated image to the size of the original image
    x = x.crop(box=(x.size[0]/2 - img.size[0]/2,
               x.size[1]/2 - img.size[1]/2,
               x.size[0]/2 + img.size[0]/2,
               x.size[1]/2 + img.size[1]/2))

    # do stuff with the rotated image here.
```

For angles other than 90° and 270° this results in the same behavior
as you get if you set `expand=False` and don't bother with the `crop`
operation.

Comment: Note that the `expand` option also reduces one of the dimensions, so cropping by itself won't be enough - you need to add some background too.

Comment: I'm not seeing that problem with `expand`.  At least for what I'm trying to do this seems to work a treat.  You can see the result [here](https://youtu.be/Fp6-uDrtd9E).  It's low resolution because this will ultimately be displayed on a 128x64 LCD.

Comment: PIL has apparently improved in the last 4 years, just img.rotate(90, expand = True) worked for me.